# Why do some early modern English writers use an apostrophe in art (ar't)?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe, contractions, early-modern-english, seventeenth-century-english

For example, in Verses upon the duke of Buckinghams returne from the Ile of Rees (https://www.english.cam.ac.uk/ceres/ehoc/lessons/lesson1/index.html) the poet spells "art" as "ar't" in the phrase "And ar't return'd again with all thy faults..."

What is that apostrophe eliding?

*Addition*: I see that the OED shows "art" as the second person singular (archaic) of the verb "to be", with a citation "1535   Bible (Coverdale) Psalms cxxvii. 2   O well is the, happie art thou." So there is a use with the following "thou", so "ar't" can't be a contraction of "are thou".

My thoughts are converging on the apostrophe being a mistake (much like so many people now use apostrophes in plurals - "Pad's available") caused by the writer thinking that "art" is a contraction of "art thou". Shakespeare uses "Art cold?", 
"art mad?" in King Lear without the apostrophe (ref First Folio), but later writers quoting King Lear insert the apostrophe for some reason (cf Wells, Poetic Imagery, 1924).

Comment: Since the Duke of Buckingham led the military expedition the  Île de Ré ('Ile of Rees') in 1627, and Queen Elizabeth I died in 1603, the tag 'elizabethan-english' is not really appropriate, and also this is a matter of transcription.

Comment: As the example is from a piece of verse it's possible that the apostrophe is an indication of non-standard pronunciation used to maintain the metre. This would make it similar to the hyphen sometimes used in hymn books giving phrases like "Bless-ed be the Lord". A grave accent is now more common but the hyphen used to be used a lot.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Since there is no jacobean-english tag, I thought elizabethan-english would be the most helpful. I don't think the language changed that much in a few years to make my use of the tag misleading. Also, this has nothing to do with transcription: the apostrophe is in the manuscript.

Comment: Quite possibly the manuscript is a copy made by a scribe.

Answer (score 2):

If the apostrophe in "ar't" is simply an error by the author, it is not the only one on this page. For example, I note three occurrences of the word "did[']st"—two without an apostrophe (*didst*) and one with an apostrophe (*did'st*). The presence or absence of the apostrophe in the case of *didst* is arguably acceptable either way—since *didst* could be read as a contracted form of "didest [thou]"—presumably the ancestral form from which *didst* sprang. Nevertheless, the lack of consistency in the writer's handling of *didst* on this page raises the possibility that he viewed apostrophes as something closer to optional ornaments than to necessary elements.

Less immediately explicable than the inconsistent treatment of *didst* and *did'st* is the word *hope't* in line 12 of the poem:

> Or didst thou hasten headlong to prevent
>
> A fruitlesse hope't for needfull parliament?

In modern U.S. English, an editor would probably render that second line as follows:

> A fruitless, hoped-for, needful Parliament?

—so it isn't as though the apostrophe in *hope't* signals the loss of, say, an *s* from *hopest*. If anything, *hopet* is a letter too long to begin with: after all, writers  generally see no reason to add an *e* (or an apostrophe) before the *t* in *burnt* or *learnt* or *spoilt* or *spilt*. (Admittedly, none of those root verbs ends with an *e*.) The case would be different if the word in the line had been *hop'd*—since that spelling clearly involves the loss of an *e*.

However, in a comment beneath this answer, Peter Shor points out that the spelling "hope't" helps the writer avoid a misreading of *hopt* or *hop't* as short forms of *hopped*, as well as to signal to readers that the word is not to be read as having two syllables (as they might if he had simply rendered the word as "hopet." As for the writer's wish to avoid "hop'd" (aside from the fact that it, too, might, be misread as a short form of "hopped"), he seems scrupulous in distinguishing between past-tense verbs and verblike adjectives ending in a "d" sound ("return'd," "distempered," "gorg'd," "wrong'd" "bespotted," "tortur'd," compos'd," "oppressed") from those ending in a "t" sound ("hope't," "vex't").

(Speaking of orthographic anomalies, in line 17, the writer renders "there's" as "their's":

> But their's a reason worse, then this, they say

—an unusual spelling to choose for a common word, although far more forgivable in 1630 than it would be today. Interchangeable use of *then* for *than*, on the other hand, seems to have been quite common in the seventeenth and eighteenth centuries.)

Returning to the line that the poster is primarily interested in:

> And ar't return'd againe wth all thy faults

one might argue that "ar't" is doing duty for two words—"art thou." However, "art" alone could have accomplished the same thing, since "art" implies "art thou," just as "dost" (as used in this poem) implies "dost thou." It seems extremely unlikely that the writer chose the spelling "ar't" because he wanted to create a contraction of the form "ar[t]'t[hou]."  I can't think of any similar use of an apostrophe to create a contraction that begins at the front of one word and ends at the front of a second word.

I consider it far more likely that the writer simply stuck the apostrophe in "ar't" on an unconsidered or ill-considered whim, without any sense that it was marking the loss of one or more letters from one or two contracted words. If you had access to more than this single page of the manuscript, you could check to see whether the writer consistently uses "ar't" for "art thou," or whether this is simply a variant form that slipped in (like "did'st" in line 9).

My guess is that the writer usually rendered the word as "art" with no apostrophe, but that on this occasion his pen or his wandering thoughts led him to a different orthographic choice. I strongly doubt, in any case, that his use of the form "ar't" was intended to adhere to some established rule of punctuation that prevailed in 1630—because I don't think that any such convention with regard to "ar[']t" existed.

Neevertheless, it is quite possible that the writer views the apostrophe as having a far wider range of uses than the modern big three of elision/contraction, possession, and pluralization. The example of "hope't" in this page indicates that the writer may use the apostrophe to indicate a pronunciation shortened from two syllables to one—and perhaps he also considers it useful for other obscure or idiosyncratic purposes, such as to distinguish "art" used in one basic sense of the word from another.

Comment: The apostrophe in *hope* signifies that it should be pronounced one-syllable *hoped* and not two-syllable *hopèd*. The author couldn't write *hopt* or *hop't* because that might be taken as *hopped* and not *hoped*. and he couldn't write *hop'd* because *hoped* ends with a /t/ and not a /d/.  Perfectly explicable. Later, the spelling in poetry signifying the one-syllable pronunciation became standardized as *hop'd.* Shakespeare (around the same time) used this convention. But the author for some reason doesn't.

Comment: `'d` (apostrophe d) was used around that time even in words where the d is pronounced [t].

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks for your comment. Your explanation of why "hopt" and "hop't" would be problematic makes sense—and I will revise my answer to indicate the practical utility of using "hope't" in avoiding misreading as two-syllable _hopèt_ or one syllable _hopped_. It still strikes me as being a rather baroque choice compared with the straightforward "hop'd"—but perhaps the writer wanted to emphasize the "t" pronunciation of the final consonant as opposed to the "d" sound that "hop'd" might imply.

Comment: The author possibly had some kind of bugaboo about writing "d" if it was suppos't to be pronounced /t/.

Comment: He uses "d" when it's pronounced /d/, as in "return'd", but later in the poem there is the line "Theire enterance sure had been impech'te awhile"

Comment: It seems to me, having read this clear analysis that the author has assumed the longest possible form of each ending and taken everything else as an abbreviation. Thus jump+ed→jumped, so hope+ed→hopeed→hope'd; speak+est→speakest, so did+est→didest→did'st and are+est→areest→ar't. I need to make it clear I am not suggesting this is where these words actually came from, but it does seem possible that this was the author's logic.

Comment: The pronunciation of past tenses isn't unusual for this author. When Shakespeare and his contemporary poets wrote, *hoped* was pronounced with two syllables *ho-pèd*, and *hop'd* was pronounced with one syllable. What is strange about this author is that he abbreviates *hoped* as *hope't* and not *hop'd*, and writes *art* as *ar't* when its not an abbreviation at all.

Comment: @PeterShor: Have you found more than this page of the manuscript somewhere online? Or is "impeach'te" on this page and I just don't see it? The writer is certainly scrupulous on this page about distinguishing between past-tense verbs and verblike adjectives ending in a "d" sound ("return'd," "distempered," "gorg'd," "wrong'd" "bespotted," "tortur'd," compos'd," "oppressed") from those ending in a "t" sound ("vex't," "hope't"). If possible, I would like to check whether he uses "ar't" consistently throughout the poem or whether this rendition is simply a one-off.

Comment: @SvenYargs: There is what seems to be a different version of this poem in Google books in the [Diary of John Rous](https://books.google.com/books?id=NYswAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22impech%27te%22&source=bl&ots=PT5bHzhGz-&sig=ACfU3U3pj0ybqD5DwT53GtnpSr5V-ekC_g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAtu_X-4zjAhVlUd8KHUTJBJ0Q6AEwA3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22impech'te%22&f=false).

Comment: Interesting... That version of the poem renders the opening of the first line as "And arte returnde againe..." and "art" appears in two subsequent lines: "Thou art the curled locke of Anti-Christ" and "Here thou art king, by William Lillies charter." But the apostrophe is lacking even in the first instance, so we can't judge from this how the writer/scribe responsible for the manuscript page in question would have handled those other two instances.